# Function giving negative value when it should be positive

Tags: function-construction

I am trying to evaluate
$$\displaystyle J=A\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}(-1)^k{n-2 \choose k}B^{n-2-k}\left(\frac{C_1}{k+n}-\frac{C_2}{k+n+1}+\frac{C_3}{k+n+2}-\frac{2}{k+n+3}\right)$$
in *Mathematica* as a function of n (i.e. `J[n]`)

Note that B, C1, C2, etc are just coefficients for some parameters I have in the model. I assign their values before I enter the function. They are given below for reference

$$\left\{\begin{array}{cc}\left((n-1)nv^{-2n}\lambda^{-n}\right)=A \\ v+\lambda v=B\end{array}\right.$$
$$\left\{\begin{array}{cc}(v^2B\lambda)=C_1 \\ (vB+(B+2v)\lambda v)=C_2 \\ (2\lambda v+B+2v)=C_3 \end{array}\right.$$

Currently I have `J[n]` coded as:

```
J[n_] := 
  a Sum[(-1^k) Binomial[n - 2, k] (b^(n - 2 - k)) 
      ((c1/(k + n)) - (c2/(k + n + 1)) - (c3/(k + n + 2)) - (2/(k + n + 3))), 
    {k, 0, n - 2}]
```

But when I call it by `J[5]` with `{v, lambda} = {1.3, 2.1}`, for instance, I get a negative value when it should be positive!

[Another user, Dolma, who helped me derive the function (it's a definite integral of another function) claims it is positive here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369799/help-evaluating-long-definite-integral)

I trust that I am doing something wrong more so than Dolma's derivation being wrong, though I should mention *Mathematica* provides a MUCH more complex answer to this integral than in the post above.

Can anyone spot where I am making a mistake?

I appreciate your time and insight!

Comment: I should add that I'm new to both stack exchange and somewhat new to Mathematica (only a user since v7), so I apologize for anything glaring I have missed.

Comment: It would be useful to see all of the code. Note that there is a difference between `(-1)^k` and `-1^k`.

Comment: I tried both the initial integral and the series you give for your provided values and get the same result $0.31644$ if you get $-0.31644$ the I think that @JonathanShock hit the spot.

Comment: EDIT- Thanks @JonathanShock Shock, this worked, I GREATLY appreciate it. I've been staring at the damn thing for too long.

Comment: ..and in your Mathematica input, your third term in the Binomial is '-(c3/(k+n+2))' whereas in your formula its '+(c3....)'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that in Mathematica there is a difference between `(-1)^k` and `-1^k`

This should solve the problem in this case.

Comment: I don't know if it's the done thing to write up an answer when a comment has solved the problem but I presume it's best to do so in order to show that it has been solved.

Comment: Followup- How often do you think people look over this distinction? I had no idea.

Comment: @BorderedHessian, can't help you there I'm afraid. If you want to know what's happening with a particular syntax then looking at the `FullForm` of the expression can be of use.